# Windows Phone 8 multiple instances of one page with MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mvvm-light

I am writing Windows Phone chat application and I would like to implement `ChatPage` which will be used to hold on a conversation view. The whole idea is to create view as much similar to SMS page as it is possible, and switch between instances of that page.

And here comes the problem - on each instance of page I need to bind the `Contact` and `ContactMessages` which are stored in XML file. I think that getting proper messages from XML file for `Contact` can be simply written in constructor. But how to open new instance of page and send it a `Contact`.

I am using MVVM Light toolkit and I could use `Messanger` to do it but how can I get sure that my `Contact` wont be registered in other instances of page. Registering an instance of `ChatPageViewModel` in that case can't be realized in `ViewModelLocator` because I need to use multiple instances of that `ViewModel` (reprimand me if I am wrong, I am newbie in MVVM light).

Is any way to achieve that? Or maybe the way I am thinking about that is totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a Service with a interface. And when the customer click on the contact, pass the parameters that this service can search an return the messages with the Contact. And every ViewModel that need this service you can inyected it from the constructor. Only you need some parameter to know which xml to read.

I dont know if a IoC container. Unity or Autofac or others can solve your problem too.

If you use Autofac you can have a similar class than this:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private IContainer container;
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();

        container = builder.Build();
    }

    public MainViewModel MainViewModel
    {
        get { return container.Resolve<MainViewModel>(); }
    }
}
```

And you can work with this instances like this parameters:

```
builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().SingleInstance();
```

for more info [here for Autofac](http://autofac.org/) and [here for Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)

Hope helps. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for this scenario, based on MVVM Light:

On a central page you have a list of all your contacts. As soon as the user selects one contact you broadcast a message that a contact has been selected. The conversation viewmodel subscribes to this message and loads the conversation from the model. The contacts viewmodel uses a [navigation service](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2011/01/navigation-in-a-wp7-application-with-mvvm-light) to navigate to the conversation view.

(Part of) The contacts ViewModel:

```
public ContactsViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
}

private RelayCommand _showConversation;

public RelayCommand ShowEvents
{
    get
    {
        return _showConversation ?? (_showConversation = new RelayCommand(ExecuteShowConversation));
    }
}

private void ExecuteShowConversation()
{
    Messenger.Default.Send(new ContactSelectedMessage(){Contact = Contact);
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri("/Views/ConversationView.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

(Part of) the Conversation ViewModel:

```
public ConversationViewModel(IDataService dataService, INavigationService navigationService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;
    _navigationService = navigationService;
    Messenger.Default.Register<ContactSelectedMessage>(this, OnContactSelected);
}

private void OnContactSelected(ContactSelectedMessage contactSelectedMessage)
{
    _dataService.GetConversation(contactSelectedMessage.Contact);
}
```

In order for the viewmodel to receive messages it should be instantiated before the message is broadcast. So, you must instantiate it in the ViewModelLocator.

In the ViewModelLocator:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
{
    /// parts missing for brevity

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ContactsViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ConversationViewModel>(true);
}
```